# display different attributes of character in a string in assembly

Tags: string, assembly, attributes, x86, character

I would like to know if its possible to change the attributes of each character in a string?

For example in the string "hello" the character 'h' will have a different color, the same with 'e' and so on.

I use AH, 06 to call every character in the string. Then use AH, 09 INT 10h to change the attribute of each character but then its not working.

I want to know how can AL (in AH, 09) get the DL (AH, 06) and change the attribute of every character.

is this possible?

thanks for the help

here's my code

`

```
.DATA
    hello   DB      "hello$" 

.CODE

START:
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    LEA SI, hello

    MOV CX, 0005H 
E:  MOV AH, 06H
    MOV DL, [SI]
    INC SI
    ;INT 21H
    LOOP E

    MOV CX, 0005H   
    MOV AH, 09H
    MOV AL, [SI]
    INC SI
    MOV BL, 0001H
H:  INT 10H
    INC BL
    LOOP H



    MOV AX, 4C00H
    INT 21H

    END START   `
```

Comment: I think you need to re-read your question because it doesn't make sense in parts. Also you didn't specify which operating system, if any, you are running on.

Comment: I just want to know if its possible to change the characters in a string with different text color. Ex. in the string "hello", 'h' will be red, 'e' will be blue, 'l' is yellow, 'l' is green and 'o' is orange. it's windows x86 and i'm using tasm.

Comment: Why is every student still using 16 bit assembler?

Answer (score 0):

First off this code is not Windows, it's 16-bit DOS code that calls the BIOS video routines.

The main body calls INT 10H, the documentation for that call is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H

For int 10H,9 this is the relevant line:

> Write character and attribute at cursor position   `AH=09h AL = Character, BH = Page Number, BL = Color, CX = Number of times to print character`

This means there are a couple of errors you're making:

1. You cannot use `CX` as a loop counter, because it's a parameter for the call.
2. The color goes into `bl` so don't hardcode that.
3. `bh` is the page number, but you're not setting `bh` anywhere.
4. Increasing bl and then later resetting it back to 1 will obviously fix it at `1`.
5. You've already increased `si` through the whole length of the string in the first loop, so in the second loop you're reading past the end of the string (a classic buffer overrun). At the start of the second loop you need to repeat the `lea`.
6. Ever since the 80486 using `loop` is a bad idea because it's much slower than the equivalent `sub reg,1; jnz label`; besides `loop` is tied to the `cx` register which is awkward.

If you're using bios `int` calls speed is hardly a requirement, but that's not the point.
If you want to learn x86 assembly you should also learn not to use the old cisc instructions on new processors.